# What options to use to convert video with a given video/audio/subtitle stream?

Tags: audio, video

I want to use `ffmpeg` to convert an video file to an output file containing one specific audio file and one specific subtitle stream.

The streams I want to choose are the following:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1036 [SAR 1:1 DAR 480:259], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
Stream #0:4(jpn): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Stream #0:6(eng): Subtitle: ass
```

so I tried the command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264  -c:a mp3lame -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:4 -map 0:s:6 output.mp4
```

but I got an error

```
Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:2. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:2
```

I do not understand that error message, as I am not selecting a 'stream 0:2'. Maybe I misunderstand the meaning of the [map option](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options)? What option to use to fix this?

Comment: The problem might be solved here : https://superuser.com/questions/1309487/ffmpeg-encoding-to-convert-video-to-pngs-with-subtitles

Comment: The *output* `stream #0:2` is the third stream in the output. The mappings should be `-map 0:0 -map 0:4 -map 0:6`, not `-map 0:s:6` for example, which refers to the seventh *subtitle* stream – you're after the absolute seventh stream – so use `0:6`. Also the audio codec should be called `libmp3lame`

Comment: Once the mappings are correct, the next problem will be trying to put subtitles into the `.mp4` container format. If possible, use the matroska (`.mkv`) format instead.

Comment: I do not understand. In the documentation it is written `-map 0:a:2` to select the third audio stream. It is not just `-map 0:2`. So what does the `a` stand for then? How to understand the documentation?

Comment: If input file `0` had 3 streams: `Stream #0:0: Video`, `Stream #0:1: Audio` & `Stream #0:2: Audio` – a stream selector `0:1` matches the second stream, which in this case would be the same as the first audio stream – `0:a:0`

Comment: When trying `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -c:a libmp3lame -c:s copy -map 0:0 -map 0:4 -map 0:6 output.mp4` instead I get an error `Could not find tag for codec ass in stream #2, codec not currently supported in container Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ass` subtitles can't go into an `mp4` container. Try using `-c:s mov_text`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -c:a libmp3lame -c:s mov_text -map 0:0 -map 0:4 -map 0:6 output.mp4
```